# Como atrasar o v-model do VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

De modo que a informação seja alterada quando o sair o foco do campo, e não a medida que se digita.

Comment: Quem é vivo sempre aparece :)

Comment: Eu voltei, aqui é meu lugar :D

Answer (score 4):

O mesmo pode ser obtido através do atributo `lazy`

Exemplo:

`<input v-model="msg" lazy>`

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando o Vue.js versão 2.x.x, o lazy deixou de ser uma propriedade e passou a ser um modificador. Então experimente `<input v-model.lazy="msg">`.